# free erp accounting manufacturing inventory fixed assets dashboards

Tags: inventory, accounting, erp

I have a new job in plastic factory that produces preform:
the current software they are using is outdated and extremely buggy.
I am in charge of straitening things up now< but I have no budget and a very limited time frame.

I need a trusted software that is:

1. "free"
2. can handle accounting financial accounting functions.
3. can handle inventory in multiple locations .
4. that works on windows OS 10 or higher.
5. we have a simple manufacturing process that should be handled.
6. Fixed assets handling would be nice
7. A simple installation and implementation process is really Appreciated.

Your recs are highly appreciated

Comment: More information would help.  Free or Paid, and other features that are a must - make a list.

Comment: Please also mention which ERPs you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

For an ERP, I would advise you start by exploring: [ERPNext](https://github.com/frappe/erpnext):

- It is free, and has accounting functions.
- It can handle inventory in multiple locations - warehouse/storage locations.
- It can run on Windows. Can also run natively or via docker

I would recommend you go through the documentation [here](https://docs.erpnext.com), before a test installation.